# I want to convert csv file to fixed width file with java

Tags: java

I want to convert CSV file into Fixed with file in Java

I have tried to copy the text from CSV to Text file,but this not solve my problem.I wanted to convert into fixed width file that is the requirement

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConvertCSVFile1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("c:\\sample1.csv"));
          int i;
          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();

          boolean a = true;
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (new PrintWriter ("C:\\Users\\sampletest.txt"), a);

          try {
              String splitBy = ",";
              String line;
              String temp;
              //ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
             // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\sample1.csv"));
              while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                   String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
                   temp = b[0]+","+b[1]+","+b[2]+","+b[3];

                   list.add(temp);
              } 


      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   finally {
          br.close ();
      }

      for (i = 0; i < list.size (); i++) {
          out.println (list.get (i));
      }

      out.flush ();
      out.close ();
}
```

}

Input

```
a   f   w   b   numinst af  ub
1RW 800 64  22  1   48:02:00    TRUE
1RW 800 16  39  1   48:02:00    TRUE
1RW 800 640 330 1   48:02:00    TRUE
1RW 800 40  124 1   48:02:00    TRUE
1RW 800 32  104 1   48:02:00    TRUE
1RW 800 8   104 1   48:02:00    TRUE
1R1W    800 65536   39  1   96:96   TRUE
1R1W    800 2048    39  1   96:96   TRUE
1R1W    800 8192    39  1   48:48:00    TRUE
```

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. There are several good CSV libraries that handle all the subtleties of the CSV format such as embedded quotes and newlines.  Use one of those to parse the CSV, then use `printf` with fixed width formats to write the data.

Comment: Ok sure,Thanks for your response

Comment: I need to convert it into Fixed width file,is that possible with CSV library.I am able to read with CSV library CSVReader

Comment: You have to write it in fixed width using printf formats.